# How do I update a column in 3rd row the same as a column in 2nd row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1093

I'm doing it this way:

```
UPDATE products 
   SET products_image = (SELECT products_image 
                           FROM products 
                          WHERE products_id = 2) 
 WHERE products_id = 3;
```

...but get an error:

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'products' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE products p1, products p2 
SET p1.products_image=p2.products_image 
WHERE p1.id=3 AND p2.id=2;
```